# find: missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: for-loop, sed, while-loop, find

All,

I have searched all over the internet and i just cant find a solution for my specific situation, i was kind of hoping you guys could help :)

I am trying to do a search and replace on a bunch of files, but i am also trying to read from a list and pass each line to the search and replace.

Here is what i got so far:

```
for i in `cat list.txt`; do find /var/www/site -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/$i//g' {} \ ; done


while read line; do find /var/www/site -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/$line//g' {} \ ; done <list.txt ;
```

In both of those examples i get the same error

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'.
```

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: You need an escaped `\;` as the final argument to `-exec`. You have an escaped space (`\ `) and then the loop terminating `;`. You want `\; ;`. Also shell variables don't expand in single quotes so you need double quotes on your sed string.

Comment: what exactly you want to do?? do u want to find a string from a list and replace it or you want to find a string from a list and then want to confirm is there any file matching that string then replace

Comment: i want to find the string from the list and delete it. then i wanna do that to all the strings on the list.